# Vfio 0000:41:00.0: failed to open /dev/vfio/32: No such file or directory - QEMU

Tags: linux, qemu

I have a NVME M.2 SSD that I would like to pass-through to my Virtual Machine as a boot, My SSD works fine with the **Virtual Machine Manager**, but when I attempt to the **Qemu:Console**, I get the following message [Saying it is not a existing file?!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXWtf.png)
[checked if it the pass-through worked!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAhUs.png)

This is the Qemu Console command I am using

```
-device vfio-pci,host=41:00.0
```

Reading on I found it was a QEMU Console *Permission error*. I can't find a way to set the vfio permission for **manjaro**, I heard something of setting a udev perms up, PCI Passthrough is working for other devices, Like my GT710 is working fine.

I then noticed that it was attached  to the host and I could not find anyway to remove it, [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AssRb.png).

Please Help me!

Answer (score 0):

You need bind your PCI device to the vfio-pci driver.

1. Unbind pci device from its previous driver

   echo "0000:00:14.0" > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/driver/unbind
2. Bind to vfio-pci driver

   echo 8086 a36d > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

> Where 8086 is the vendor id of the PCI device, and a36d is device id of the PCI device

3. Check and vfio group should be present, and Qemu can run.

   ls -l /dev/vfio/